# Is it a "paradox", or a flaw in the question?

Tags: puzzle, infinity, paradoxes

(Clearly not a pardox per-se but I would like to hear what you think)

The basic riddle (not a very interesting one even) goes as follows:

A first client comes into a barber shop, takes a hair cut and the barber tells him "check how much money there's inside the cash box, double it and take $\$20$ change back.

A second client comes, takes a hair cut and the barber tells him "check how much money there's inside the cash box, double it and take $\$20$ change back.

Same story with the third client, who happens to be the last one.

At the end of the day the barber checks the box and it's empty. How much money was in the box at the beginning of the day?

So, it's not too difficult to compute and to get that the answer is $\$17.5$.

Generalizing for $N$ people, and for $K$ amount of change each time, we get that in the beginning of the day there was

$$K \cdot \frac{2^N -1}{2^N}$$ initial amount in the box.

Now, what happens when there are infinitely many clients? The limit of the above sequence is clearly $K$ but on the other hand that would mean that even though each client is doubling the amount in the box and taking half of it, after infinitely many clients the box is empty!

I think that the "paradox" here lies within the question itself. You can't talk about what happens after infinitely many clients.

Am I right?

Comment: "So, it's not too difficult to compute and to get that the answer is $\$17.5$.". What if there's no money from the start? What if there is less than $\$10$? After the first client doubles and takes twenty there will be nothing left.

Comment: The assumption is that no client ever faces that difficulty and after the last client there's nothing in the box.

Comment: There is an issue when you say there are an infinity of customers given that there is a last one... If you want to rephrase it the other way, that's OK...

Comment: You **can** talk about it. I've seen it done.

Comment: Ok, say $K=20$ and $N=\infty$. Each client drops $\$20$ in the box and takes out $\$20$. What's in the box at infinity? That depends. Does each client take back his own twenty, or does each client leave his twenty in the box and take the old twenty?

Comment: @bof how that makes a difference?

Comment: @AmihaiZivan If each client takes back his own twenty, then the original twenty is there all along, untouched; might as well be glued to the box. If each client takes the previous twenty, then whose twenty dollar bill is going to be there at the end? Each bill was only there for the duration of one haircut.

Comment: As @Martigan said though, given the constraints of this problem you can't simultaneously talk about the "last" client while trying to discuss an infinite number of customers. There's really nothing paradoxical about it, because (mathematically), that value will *approach* K, but it will never actually *reach* K.

Comment: Mathematically, the limit of the sequence of sets$$\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1\},\{1,3\},\{1\},\{1,4\},\{1\},\{1,5\},\dots$$is the set $\{1\}$, while the limit of the sequence$$\{1\},\{1,2\},\{2\},\{2,3\},\{3\},\{3,4\},\{4\},\{4,5\},\dots$$is the empty set. Now, if you want to ask what happens if you try the experiment with actual banknotes, or elementary particles, that's not a mathematical question.

Comment: Your spelling of puzzle is wrong, so you have unknowingly created a new tag called 'puzle'.

Comment: As the number of customers increases, the amount originally in the drawer would approach $20. The unique thing about limits is that they sometimes defy our expectations of what should happen.